TypeError: navigation.openDrawer is not a function (it is undefined) js engine: hermes in React Native
I'm using React Navigation in my React Native project with a combination of Stack Navigator and Drawer Navigator, but when I try to use navigation.openDrawer() in my component, I'm getting the following error:

ERROR  TypeError: navigation.openDrawer is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes

Code Overview:
Home.js
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';<br>
const navigation = useNavigation();

const LeftIcon = () => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.pr15}
        onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
          <Ionicons
          name="menu"
          color={colors.textColor}
          size={moderateScale(30)}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

<LeftIcon />

NavigationKeys.js
export const TabNav = {
  Home: 'Home',
  Profile: 'Profile',
  Library: 'Library',
  Explore: 'Explore',
  DrawerNavigation: 'DrawerNavigation',
};
export const DrawerNav = {
  Home: 'Home',
  Profile: 'Profile',
  Library: 'Library',
  Explore: 'Explore',
};

NavigationRoutes.js
import DrawerNavigation from './Type/DrawerNavigation';

export const TabRoute = {
  Home,
  Profile,
  Library,
  Explore,
  DrawerNavigation,
};
export const DrawerRoute = {
  Home,
  Profile,
  Library,
  Explore,
};

StackNavigation.js
<Stack.Screen
        name={TabNav.DrawerNavigation}
        component={TabRoute.DrawerNavigation}
      />

I’ve tried using navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer()) from @react-navigation/drawer instead of navigation.openDrawer(), but I still get the same error.


If you're trying to open the drawer from a component that doesn't have direct access to the drawer navigation, you can use DrawerActions to trigger an action to open the drawer
import { DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

// Update in your component
const LeftIcon = () => {
const navigation = useNavigation(); // Confirm this is inside the component

 return (
   <TouchableOpacity style={styles.pr15}
     onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}>
     <Ionicons name="menu" color={colors.textColor} size={moderateScale(30)} />
   </TouchableOpacity>
 );
};

export default LeftIcon;


Updated navigation code
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import HomeScreen from './Home';
import ProfileScreen from './Profile';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function MyDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Main" component={MyStack} />
      {/* Other drawer screens */}
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
   <NavigationContainer>
     <MyDrawer />
   </NavigationContainer>
 );
}



